# How to convert basic disk to dynamic on windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, vds

What win apis exist to convert basic disk to dynamic? I would really appreciate if someone can share sample code. I came across IVdsPack::MigrateDisks but I am not able to find any sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but look into the [Virtual Disk Service doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb986750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Specially [IVdsDisk::ConvertStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you target Windows 8 and later you can use the [Windows Storage Management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830613%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: IVdsDisk::ConvertStyle converts partition style of disk. Like MBR to GPT and vice-versa. I went through VDS doc and cant find anything closely related to converting disks other than MigrateDisks.